# Colour cells based around average of column for whole sheet

Tags: excel

I am attemping to colour cells which are pupils test results in excel.

I wish to colour them based on if they are more than 10% of the test total above average (green colour) or more than 10% of the test total below average (red colour) and those within 10% of the test total above or below average remain uncoloured.

eg, if a test is out of 30, green for those more than 3 above average and red for those more than 3 below average

eg if a test is out of 200, green for those more than 20 above average and red for those more than 20 below average

I have results in columns, each column is a different test.

Thanks!

Comment: Conditional formatting should be able to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone is right; you can do this with conditional formatting.

I'm assuming you have a row that contains the max score for each test (row 2 in my example).

- Select all the test scores (all columns) and click `Conditional Formatting` on the Home ribbon. Choose `New Rule...`.
- Choose `Use a formula to determine which cells to format.` Enter the following formula:

  ```
  =B3>AVERAGE(B$3:B$32)+0.1*B$2
  ```

  where the first full column of test scores is in `B3:B32` and the max score for the first test is in `B2`.
- Set your format for the cell (green). And you're done.

Repeat this for the red cells using this formula:

```
=B3<AVERAGE(B$3:B$32)-0.1*B$2
```

[image]

Comment: @StuartPatterson .. you should mark this as the answer !! .. make a green tick below 'downvote sign' ..

Answer (score 0):

There is something called [conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx) that can be used to accomplish what you want

Comment: tried using it but it bases whole sheet on one cell, I wish to base it column by column on column average!